# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (9801) must match the size of tensor b (3137) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to build a sequence to sequence model where I pass 100 frames from a video to the Vivit model, and get binary cross entropy outputs for each frame.

I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-1abb7eea0394> in <cell line: 1>()
     26         inputs = inputs.reshape(inputs.shape[1:])
     27         print(inputs.shape)
---> 28         frame_logits = model(inputs)
     29         labels = labels.unsqueeze(2).expand(-1, -1, inputs.size(2))
     30         loss = criterion(frame_logits, labels)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-84-43865859a735> in forward(self, pixel_values)
     29         # ViViT model forward pass
     30         #print(pixel_values.shape)
---> 31         outputs = self.vivit(pixel_values=pixel_values)
     32 
     33         # Extract the hidden states

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/vivit/modeling_vivit.py in forward(self, pixel_values, head_mask, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    722         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
    723 
--> 724         outputs = self.vivit(
    725             pixel_values,
    726             head_mask=head_mask,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/vivit/modeling_vivit.py in forward(self, pixel_values, head_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    583         head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, self.config.num_hidden_layers)
    584 
--> 585         embedding_output = self.embeddings(pixel_values)
    586 
    587         encoder_outputs = self.encoder(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/vivit/modeling_vivit.py in forward(self, pixel_values)
    114 
    115         # add positional encoding to each token
--> 116         embeddings = embeddings + self.position_embeddings
    117 
    118         embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (9801) must match the size of tensor b (3137) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Vivit Huggingface documentation:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/vivit

Following is the code for the model:

```
class VideoClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config, num_frames):
        super(VideoClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.num_frames = num_frames
        self.vivit = VivitForVideoClassification(config)
        
        # Add a custom binary classification head for each frame
        self.classification_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()  # Apply sigmoid activation for binary classification
        )

    def forward(self, pixel_values):
        # ViViT model forward pass
        #print(pixel_values.shape)
        outputs = self.vivit(pixel_values=pixel_values)

        # Extract the hidden states
        hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state

        # Reshape the hidden states to separate frames
        hidden_states = hidden_states.view(-1, self.num_frames, hidden_states.size(-1))

        # Pass each frame through the binary classification head
        frame_logits = self.classification_head(hidden_states)

        return frame_logits  # Shape: (batch_size, num_frames, 1)

model = VideoClassifier(config, num_frames = 100 )
```

Following is the code for the training loop:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    all_frame_logits = []
    total_loss = 0

    for batch in train_data_loader:
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        inputs, *labels = batch
        
        #print(labels)
        #inputs = image_processor(list(inputs), return _tensors = "pt")
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        '''
        outputs =  model(inputs['pixel_values'])
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

        all_frame_logits.extend(outputs)
        print(total_loss)
        '''
        inputs = {key: val.to(device) for key, val in inputs.items()}
        inputs = inputs['pixel_values']
        print(inputs.shape)
        inputs = inputs.reshape(inputs.shape[1:])
        print(inputs.shape)
        frame_logits = model(inputs)
        labels = labels.unsqueeze(2).expand(-1, -1, inputs.size(2))
        loss = criterion(frame_logits, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()

    average_loss = total_loss / len(train_data_loader)

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}:")
    print(f"Average Loss: {average_loss}")
    model_name = "fine_tuned_vivit_multithumos_BaseballPitch_epoch_"+epoch
    model.save_pretrained(model_name)
```

The inputs have been processed using the VivitImageProcessor module on huggingface.